# apache CustomLog with multiple env?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, httpd

I have 2 CustomLog statements:

```
# SVN-ACTION is default env
CustomLog logs/svn_access_log common env=SVN-ACTION
SetEnvIf Request_Method GET GET-ACTION
CustomLog logs/get_access_log common env=GET-ACTION
```

That works, but the CustomLog statement below doesn't work... it prints an error:

```
CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log common env=!GET-ACTION env=!SVN-ACTION
```

How can I use multiple env conditions in CustomLog?

Comment: You tagged your question as apache-2.2 and apache-2.4. Which is it? The answer depends on which Apache version you're using.

Comment: I remove apache-2.2 tag

Answer (score 2):

use this:

`CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log common \
    "expr=(-z reqenv('GET-ACTION') && -z reqenv('SVN_ACTION'))"`

the whole third argument seems to need double quotes. quoting right-side of "=" only is not enough.

syntax tested with version 2.4.34.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache 2.4 you can use an [expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

For example:

```
CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log common \
  "expr=-z reqenv('GET-ACTION') && -z reqenv('SVN_ACTION')"
```

Comment: It doesn't work... error message is "CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" or "expr=" clause (see docs)"

Comment: @Nathan thanks for the edit, which I think addresses Somputer's comment.